# nginx try_files and multiple location blocks

Tags: nginx

I have 2 domains, each with its own document root.
The root of one domain contains the folders pics and docs that I want accessible through the other domain.
So domain1.com/pics/house.jpg and domain2.com/pics/house.jpg would show the same image.

Below is an excerpt from the config file for domain2. It doesn't work - I always get a 404 when accesing the image in domain1 root on domain2. I'd welcome any suggestions on how to rewrite this to fix it. Thank you

```
root /home/admin/domain2.com/html;

index index.php index.html;

location /pics/ {
       root /home/admin/domain1.com;
}

location /docs/ {
       root /home/admin/domain1.com;
}

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

Comment: Please post the full config. It looks like root of domain1.com is `/home/admin/domain1.com/html` and `pics` folder is at `/home/admin/domain1.com/html/pics`. Anyway, most such issues can be resolved by creating a symlink, rather than re-configuring Nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, my code didn't work for cases where /pics/ contained further folders. Using the following worked.

```
location ^~ /pics/ {
       root /home/admin/domain1.com;
       # Queries beginning with /pics/ and then stops searching.
}
```